# Cygwin SSH client timeout on login

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

I can't get an SSH connection to stick.
I ran `ssh user%server@host -v` and got this output

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gw.cs.huji.ac.il [132.65.116.14] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 132.65.116.14 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host gw.cs.huji.ac.il port 22: Connection timed out
```

I am running this on Cygwin on Windows 10. I tried configuring the firewall to allow "ssh.exe", port 22, and some other configurations to no avail.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Is the sshd running? Is it configured to listen on 132.65.116.14?

Comment: Yes and yes. I have no trouble connecting to this machine with the exact same command through a Linux or windows machine, but with windows I'm clueless. I believe that this may be a firewall issue but I am unable to solve it

Comment: @BelgishChoko 132.65.116.14 port 22 is publicly reacheable. Try to make sure Windows Firewall is disabled.